# Domain driven design can value objects reference / embed an entity

Tags: php, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, domain-model, value-objects

I have a small issue understanding ddd value objects, so a couple questions has raised from my domain that i really need help solving them,

First question :

Lets say i have a `car` entity and `wheel` value object the `wheel` has a two entities which are `rubber` and `rims` so the issue is the wheel allowed to have entities inside it?

example :

```
namespace Domain\ValueObjects;

class Wheel{

    private $rim;

    private $rubber;

    public function __construct(Domain\Models\Rim $rim, Domain\Models\Rubber $rubber){
        $this->rim = $rim->toArray();
        $this->rubber = $rubber->toArray();
    }
}
```

Second question :

when i map the `car` from my infrastructure to an actual domain model how im gonna map the rim if i wanna say return the wheel rim, in another word how im gonna construct an object of type rim from the wheel ? is it a static function like `public static function fromNative()`;

Note :

to be more specific about question two as you may notice when im constructing the value objects, im setting the object as native type which is `array` so i remove mapping responsibility from the `ODM`, is that a good practice or should i leave that responsibility to `ODM`.

Comment: Why did you model `rubber` and `rim` as entities while `wheel` is only a value object ? What are the reasons you designed your domain that way ?

Comment: `rubber` and `rims` have brands so i already have this in my domain persisted so the user can choose from diffrent brands, but i dont store `wheel` its represent the both but has no identifier to say that this wheel is defferent form anohter wheel unless the wheel has a diffrent `rubber` or `rim`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to your first question, value objects represent an object which has no identity and is only comparable by it's value.  Entities have identity, so even if their values are the same, they are still different objects fundamentally.  So in your scenario, once you include entities within a value object, then you no longer have a value object since you can't compare it based on value alone.

If rim and rubber are value objects however, then it's fine to have a composite wheel value object.

For the second question, if you are asking how to create an entity which has a value object from within your data layer, then I suggest you do if from the ODM if possible.  Sometimes custom mapping may be required depending on how complex it is.  I would definitely avoid any methods which serve infrastructure concerns to be added to the domain objects.

Comment: thank you for answering @tyler-day but my concern is that i cant say that `rubber` and `rim` are value objects on my domain cause they need to exist in my inventory so i can say that they are valid, so if we say that the `wheel` cant be a value object, is it a `Aggregate` or what ?

Comment: It sounds like your wheel object is actually an aggregate in that case.

Comment: cool but i still have a question that is, can an aggregate exist without an identifier ?

Comment: No, aggregates need a unique identifier.  If you have no identifier how would you reference it?  In a simple example, consider you have 2 identical wallets, each with $50 in it.  One belongs to Steve, and the other belongs to Joe.  Would you say they are the same wallet?  If yes, then it's a value object.  If no, then it's an entity.

Comment: then the `wheel` is a value object i guess in my domain, notice when i  construct the `wheel` i inject a full object of `Rims`, `Rubber` inside it so those entities have identifiers , its valid that wheel to be equal to another wheel it must have the same `rubber` , `rims` inside it as a full object that has the same idetifiers, and if the domain enforce that role then i cant help it but to follow my domain roles, do you agree ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree. As I said in my answer, if a value object is composed of entities, then you no longer have a value object.  It sounds like maybe rims and rubber aren't really true entities though, and just maybe a product code or something relating to the actual entity.  In which case I guess you are fine nested them under a wheel value object.

Comment: after a couple of tests i actually find out that your answer is correct, i guess i was thinking too much about persistence, i thank you very much for clearing out my perspective

Comment: +1 to @TylerDay's comment, IMO it all depends if `Wheel` is a SKU (real copy of a manufactured product in your stock) or just a model of wheel, as would appear in a product catalog.